# Problemas con el linker para la el uso de OpenGL con C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer uso de OpenGL y tras instalar las librerías correspondientes y compilar un ejemplo, el linker me da error de que no encuentra las librerías correspondientes. Uso Cygwin en el IDE Eclipse.

El error en concreto es el siguiente:

```
15:43:25 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project PRUEBA_OPENGL_01 ****
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
g++ -I"C:\cygwin64\usr\include\w32api" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: PRUEBA_OPENGL_01.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++ -L-C:\cygwin64\lib -o "PRUEBA_OPENGL_01.exe"  ./main.o   -l-lopengl32\ -lglu32\ -lfreeglut
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -l-lopengl32 -lglu32 -lfreeglut
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:49: PRUEBA_OPENGL_01.exe] Error 1

15:43:28 Build Finished (took 2s.534ms)
```

El problema en concreto es con la librería "freeglut", la cual ya instale desde el instalador de Cygwin.

El código de ejemplo que he usado es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(0.25,0.25,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75,0.25,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75,0.75,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.25,0.75,0.0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0);
}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250,250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("hello");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Tal y como se puede comprobar he escrito los parámetros "-lopengl32\ -lglu32\ -lfreeglut" en la configuración del linker.

Me gustaría saber qué puedo hacer para solucionar este problema, he estado investigando y todo lo que encontrado y probado me seguía dando los mismos errores.

Un saludo.

Comment: fíjate que en el primer caso no estás poniendo `-lopengl32` sino `-l-lopengl32` y las librerías no van con la barra final usa `-lopengl32` en vez de `-lopengl32\`

Comment: Muchas gracias eferion, solucionaste mi problema, no me di cuenta de que las librerías no estaban bien introducidas. Me estaba volviendo loco, pero ya todo funciona sin problemas. Muchas gracias y un saludo

Comment: Me alegro. Lo pongo entonces como respuesta por si alguien se encuentra con un problema similar

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tenemos dos problemas, y los dos están relacionados con la declaración de las librerías en el enlazador:

**Prefijo duplicado**

en el caso de la primera librería, estás usando el prefijo `-l` **dos veces** seguidas:

```
-l-lopengl32\ -lglu32\ -lfreeglut
^^^^
```

Cuando lo esperable sería:

```
-lopeng32
```

**Las librerías no llevan barras**

Fíjate que las dos primeras librerías terminan con una barra:

```
-l-lopengl32\ -lglu32\ -lfreeglut
            ^        ^
```

Esas declaraciones son incorrectas. Las barras sobran, sin más.

Resumiendo, la declaración de las librerías sería:

```
-lopengl32 -lglu32 -lfreeglut
```